# Suppress SSRS Report blank pages when controls have dynamic content - workarounds?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

There's lots of answers as to "why is this happening", or "what to look for"... but... there isn't a way to just suppress blank pages if there's data being rendered on them?  No workaround other than tweaking things for hours to get it to *not* create blank pages?  I have a report that has a matrix with dynamic content in it, and I get a blank page every other page regardless of how much I tweak the dimensions of the report... but it needs to grow with more data.

At the risk of sounding like a rant, it's difficult for me to believe, from a usability standpoint, that there is no mechanism to just suppress pages with no rendered data on them, but it seems like that is the case.  If so, is there a "hack" that will allow me to suppress these pages, maybe after rendering?  Or to truncate rendered data that goes outside of the dimensions of the page instead of putting it on another page?  I am not a report designer by trade, and spending 10+ hours on this silly thing is seriously frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I set the report's `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace` property to `True`, this problem went away:

[image: ConsumeContainerWhiteSpaceProperty]